# Improving Encryption Algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, key

Recently I had started this assignment just meant for school purposes but I have recently decided that I would want to continue this as a new project and wanted suggestions on how I can improve my algorithm. I had an idea where I wanted the encryption key to change per character to make my encryption more secure but I have been having difficulty with this as It wouldn't work out and I couldnt decrypt my final encrypted text

Here is the encrypter:

```
text = input('Enter A Word : ') ##This asks a user for an input of text integers etc
encrypt = '' ##Empty Value used to store the encrypted value
temp = '' ##Empty temp value replaced at every iteration of the encryption process
temp2 =0 ##Empty temp value replaced at every iteration of the encryption process
temp_val=0
temp_char=''
rtext= text[::-1]
key=int(input('Enter your key (Your Encrypted Sentence Will Further be Encrypted Later) : '))##key used to shift the letters



for a in range (0,len(rtext)):
    if len(rtext) % 2==0:
        hlength=len(rtext)/2
    else:
        hlength=(len(rtext)+1)/2
print(hlength)
for i in range(int(hlength),len(rtext)):
    ##Rearranges text in a caps switch
    if str.islower(rtext[i])==True:
        temp=temp+str.upper(rtext[i])
    elif str.isupper(rtext[i])==True:
        temp=temp+str.lower(rtext[i])
    else:
        temp=temp+rtext[i]
for b in range(0,int(hlength)):
    ##Rearranges text in a caps switch
    if str.islower(rtext[b])==True:
        temp=temp+str.upper(rtext[b])
    elif str.isupper(rtext[b])==True:
        temp=temp+str.lower(rtext[b])
    else:
        temp=temp+rtext[b]
for j in range(0,len(temp)):
    temp_val=0
    temp2=0
    temp_val=ord(temp[j])
    temp2=temp2+temp_val+int(key)
    temp_char=temp_char+chr(temp2)
    encrypt=temp_char
print(encrypt)
print(temp)
print(temp2)
```

The Decrypter:

```
text = input('Enter A Word : ') ##This asks a user for an input of text integers etc
decrypt = '' ##Empty Value used to store the encrypted value
order=0
characters=''
temp=''
rtext=text[::-1]

key=int(input('Enter your key (decryption) : '))##key used to shift the letters

for i in range (0,len(rtext)):
    order=0
    order=order+ord(rtext[i])-int(key)
    characters=characters+chr(order)
for a in range (0,len(rtext)):
    if len(rtext) % 2==0:
        hlength=len(rtext)/2
    else:
        hlength=(len(rtext)+1)/2
for j in range (int(hlength),len(characters)):
    if str.islower(characters[j])==True:
        temp=temp+str.upper(characters[j])
    elif str.isupper(characters[j])==True:
        temp=temp+str.lower(characters[j])
    else:
        temp=temp+characters[j]
for b in range (0,int(hlength)):
    if str.islower(characters[b])==True:
        temp=temp+str.upper(characters[b])
    elif str.isupper(characters[b])==True:
        temp=temp+str.lower(characters[b])
    else:
        temp=temp+characters[b]
print(temp)
```

I specifically want to change the variable key.

ord() - Turns characters into its Ascii equivalent
chr() - Turns Ascii numbers into its character equivalent
rtext - gets the inverse of the users input

Comment: There are many things you should do to your code first to make it easier to read, eg.: `str.islower(characters[b]) == True` is just a long-winded way of writing `characters[b].islower()`, `range(0, len(rtext))` can be written as just `range(len(rtext))`, `temp = temp + xxx` can be written as `temp += xxx`, and the `if len(rtext) % 2 == 0 ...` can be written as `hlength = len(rtext) // 2 + len(rtext) % 2`

Answer (score 2):

If we simplify the code in the encryptor a little, we get:

```
def encrypt_text(text: str, key: int):
    print("TEXT:", text, "KEY:", key)
    temp = ''
    temp2 = 0
    temp_val = 0
    temp_char = ''
    rtext = text[::-1]
    print("RTEXT:", rtext)

    hlength = len(rtext) // 2 + len(rtext) % 2   # half, round up
    print("HLENGTH:", hlength)

    for i in range(hlength, len(rtext)):
        # Rearrange text in a caps switch
        if rtext[i].islower():
            temp += rtext[i].upper()
        elif rtext[i].isupper():
            temp += rtext[i].lower()
        else:
            temp += rtext[i]

    print("TEMP:", temp)

    for b in range(0, int(hlength)):
        # Rearrange text in a caps switch
        if rtext[b].islower():
            temp += rtext[b].upper()
        elif rtext[b].isupper():
            temp += rtext[b].lower()
        else:
            temp += rtext[b]

    for j in range(len(temp)):
        temp_val = 0
        temp2 = 0
        temp_val = ord(temp[j])
        temp2 = temp2 + temp_val + int(key)
        temp_char = temp_char + chr(temp2)
        encrypt = temp_char

    print("ENCRYPT:", encrypt)
    print("TEMP:", temp)
    print("TEMP2:", temp2)
    return encrypt


text = "hello world"
key = 42
print("ENCRYPTED:", encrypt_text(text, key))
```

I've put it inside a function (and added some print statements), so it becomes easier to work with while developing. The code is essentially the same as yours, except

```
for a in range (0,len(rtext)):
    if len(rtext) % 2==0:
        hlength=len(rtext)/2
    else:
        hlength=(len(rtext)+1)/2
```

is replaced by

```
hlength = len(rtext) // 2 + len(rtext) % 2   # half, round up
```

which gives the same result (except `hlength` is an integer).

Your first two for loops do the same operation (switches case on a string). We can write a function for that:

```
def swap_case(str):
    res = ''
    for ch in str:
        if ch.islower():
            res += ch.upper()
        elif ch.isupper():
            res += ch.lower()
        else:
            res += ch
    return res
```

and now we can replace the first two for loops with calls to our function:

```
temp += swap_case(rtext[hlength:len(rtext)])  # or shorter rtext[hlength:]
temp += swap_case(rtext[0:hlength])           # or shorter rtext[:hlength]
```

it just happend that `.swapcase()` is already a string method, so we didn't really need our swap_case function, and could just write:

```
temp += rtext[hlength:].swapcase()
temp += rtext[:hlength].swapcase()
```

Your third for-loop:

```
for j in range(len(temp)):
    temp_val = 0                          # this value is not used (it's overwritten 2 lines down)
    temp2 = 0
    temp_val = ord(temp[j])              
    temp2 = temp2 + temp_val + int(key)   # temp2 is always zero at this point
    temp_char = temp_char + chr(temp2)
    encrypt = temp_char
```

can be simplified to (the initial value of `temp_char` is set to the empty string above):

```
for j in range(len(temp)):       # for each index position (j)
    temp_val = ord(temp[j])      # use the character at from temp at index j
    temp2 = temp_val + int(key)  # key is already an int from your: key=int(input('Enter your key (decryption) : '))
    temp_char += chr(temp2)
    encrypt = temp_char          # hmm... just overwriting encrypt on every iteration
```

the comments mean that it could be even simpler:

```
encrypt = ''
for character in temp:
    temp_val = ord(character)
    temp2 = temp_val + key
    encrypt += chr(temp2)
```

This leaves us with (the comments enumerate the steps taken):

```
def encrypt_text(text: str, key: int):
    temp = ''
    rtext = text[::-1]                           # (1) reverse the string

    hlength = len(rtext) // 2 + len(rtext) % 2   # (2) split the string on hlength
    second_part = rtext[hlength:].swapcase()     #  .. and swap case on the parts
    first_part = rtext[:hlength].swapcase()
    temp += second_part                          # (3) and put the second part..
    temp += first_part                           # ..  before the first part

    encrypt = ''
    for character in temp:
        temp_val = ord(character)
        temp2 = temp_val + key                   # (4) add key to every character
        encrypt += chr(temp2) 

    return encrypt
```

to decrypt a string encrypted with this function, we need to do the operations "backwards and opposite":

```
def decrypt_text(encrypted, key):
    temp = ''
    for ch in encrypted:
        temp += chr(ord(ch) - key)   # subtract key from every character (4)

    hlength = len(encrypted) // 2 + len(encrypted) % 2
    half = len(encrypted) - hlength  # the split point is a mirror image of what it is in encrypt_text (3)

    rtext = ''
    rtext += temp[half:].swapcase()  # re-assemble the string and swap case (2)
    rtext += temp[:half].swapcase()

    text = rtext[::-1]               # finally reverse (1)
    return text
```

Comment: Thank you, I really like your approach to the program. In school we are kind of forced into thinking in a certain way to get our programs done. I overcomplicated my program when I knew I should have been using a function to shrink it down.

Comment: How do you think I should implement the changing key(for each character), I wanted to use a digit such as 99/70 which is then converted back to an integer but I havent been getting any luck, Please write this as a seperate answer if you know

Comment: I've added another answer that explains variable length keys etc.  Remember to upvote any answer you find helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of using longer keys (similar to your one-key-per-character), is to use the xor function, which in Python is written as `^` (pronounced either 'hat' or 'xor'), as in:

```
a ^ b  # true if either a, or b are true, but not both
```

Here is some background on how it works, although you don't really need to understand this to use it...

> This operator work on bits.  To see what is happening, lets define a
>   function to print the bit representation of an integer (you don't need
>   to understand this):
>
> ```
> def bits(n):
>     return bin(n)[2:].zfill(4)
> ```
>
> then we have we can show the bit patterns of integers 5 and 9, and the
>   operation `5 ^ 9`:
>
> ```
> bits(5)      => 0101
> bits(9)      => 1001
> --------------------
> bits(5 ^ 9)  => 1100
> ====================
> ```
>
> if you look at the bit patterns, there is a 1 in the result where
>   there is exactly one 1 in the column above, so from left to right (0 ^
>   1 = 1, 1 ^ 0 = 1, 0 ^ 0 = 0, and 1 ^ 1 = 0).
>
> Knowing the above, you can verify that for any number `k ^ k == 0`,
>   and `n ^ 0 == n`, and therefore `n ^ k ^ k == n`.

The useful thing about xor is that for any number `n`:

```
n ^ key ^ key == n
```

ie. xor-ing the number with key, twice, gives you back the number.

Let's use this to encrypt (`zip(text, key)` returns one character from text and key at a time, in lock-step, until one of them is "used up"):

```
def encrypt_xor(text: str, key: str):
    if len(key) < len(text):
        # key must be longer because of how zip works..
        raise ValueError("Key must be at least as long as text")

    res = ''
    for ch, k in zip(text, key):
        res += chr(ord(ch) ^ ord(k))
    return res
```

if you try to `print(encrypt_text('hello', 'world'))` you'll get gibberish printed to your screen (since the value you get by xor-ing two characters isn't necessarily printable).  The cool thing about xor is that the decrypt function is exactly the same as the encrypt function, so encrypting twice gives you the original value:

```
text = 'hello'
key  = 'world'
cipher = encrypt_xor(text, key)    # encrypted text is often called cipher
print(encrypt_xor(cipher, key))    # prints 'hello'
```

You can use a similar structure for shift-type encryption (but without the convenience that the decrypt function is the same as the encrypt), e.g.:

```
def encrypt_shift(text: str, key: str):
    res = ''
    for ch, k in zip(text, key):
        res += chr(ord(ch) + ord(k))   # add the char from the key
    return res

def decrypt_shift(text: str, key: str):
    res = ''
    for ch, k in zip(text, key):
        res += chr(ord(ch) - ord(k))   # subtract the char from the key
    return res

text = 'hello'
key  = 'world'
cipher = encrypt_shift(text, key)
print(decrypt_shift(cipher, key))   # prints 'hello
```

to avoid the unpleasantness of needing a key that is longer than the text, we can start using the key from the beginning again if there is more text left. The `itertools.cycle(..)` function does this for us:

```
import itertools

def encrypt_shift(text: str, key: str):
    res = ''
    for ch, k in zip(text, itertools.cycle(key)):
        res += chr(ord(ch) + ord(k))
    return res

def decrypt_shift(text: str, key: str):
    res = ''
    for ch, k in zip(text, itertools.cycle(key)):
        res += chr(ord(ch) - ord(k))
    return res
```

now

```
text = 'hello world'
key  = 'world'
cipher = encrypt_shift(text, key)
print(decrypt_shift(cipher, key))   # prints 'hello world' (not just 'hello' -- the first len(key) characters)
```

This can be plugged into the encrypt_text and decrypt_text functions from the other answer:

```
def encrypt_text(text: str, key: str):           # key is now a string
    temp = ''
    rtext = text[::-1]                           # (1) reverse the string

    hlength = len(rtext) // 2 + len(rtext) % 2   # (2) split the string on hlength
    second_part = rtext[hlength:].swapcase()     #  .. and swap case on the parts
    first_part = rtext[:hlength].swapcase()
    temp += second_part                          # (3) and put the second part..
    temp += first_part                           # ..  before the first part

    encrypt = encrypt_shift(temp, key)           # (4) shift each char using key
    return encrypt
```

and

```
def decrypt_text(encrypted, key):
    temp = decrypt_shift(encrypted, key)  # unshift each char using key

    hlength = len(encrypted) // 2 + len(encrypted) % 2
    half = len(encrypted) - hlength  # the split point is a mirror image of what it is in encrypt_text (3)

    rtext = ''
    rtext += temp[half:].swapcase()  # re-assemble the string and swap case (2)
    rtext += temp[:half].swapcase()

    text = rtext[::-1]               # finally reverse (1)
    return text
```